# Azure Data Catalog Assets are not editable when I register an asset via REST API

Tags: azure-data-catalog

I am using the REST API of Azure Data Catalog to register new assets. My users need to be able to add/change tags and description. However, when I register new assets over REST API, add tag buttons and description text field disappear.

I suspect I need to pass a parameter in the json to make the fields editable. In the official documentation I couldn't find anything related.

I have all of the admin rights in all of my users, so I don't think it is an access rights issue.

How can I make the assets editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-catalog/data-catalog-developer-concepts#examples). By default, the assets that are created by REST API are only editable by their owners. In order to change that behaviour, the following json object should be added to the payload:

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "Contributor",
            "members": [
                {
                    "objectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000201"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

   //properties start here
   //"properties": {
   //...
   // }
}
```

if it is still unclear, please check the following sample [code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-catalog-dotnet-service-principal-get-started/blob/master/Program.cs#L297).